# Call stored procedure and cursor parameter with OleDb

Tags: c#, oracle, oledb, oledbdatareader

I'm developing an application in C# that connects to an Oracle 10g database.

I'm using Oledb like this:

```
OleDbConnection conn = ConnectionUtil.CreateConexion();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = SP_AUTENTICAR_USUARIO;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_SED_USUARIO", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strUsuario;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_SED_PASS", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = strPass;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_cursor", OleDbType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;//I dont know what to put here

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

OleDbDataReader objReader = (OleDbDataReader)cmd.Parameters["p_cursor"].Value;

if (objReader.Read())
{...
```

I need to call a stored procedure and read a cursor with `OleDbDataReader`.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Please Check this sample code.this is using OracleDataReader

```
oraConn.Open();

OracleCommand cursCmd = new OracleCommand("CURSPKG.OPEN_TWO_CURSORS", oraConn);
cursCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cursCmd.Parameters.Add("EMPCURSOR", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cursCmd.Parameters.Add("DEPTCURSOR", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

OracleDataReader rdr = cursCmd.ExecuteReader();

Console.WriteLine("\nEmp ID\tName");

while (rdr.Read())
  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}, {2}", rdr.GetOracleNumber(0), rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(2));

rdr.NextResult();

Console.WriteLine("\nDept ID\tName");

while (rdr.Read())
  Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", rdr.GetOracleNumber(0), rdr.GetString(1));

rdr.Close();
oraConn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, butI know how to do this with OracleDataReader, but I need to use oledbd